# What's the procedure of the Tory party if the Prime Minister lost his seat in the upcoming UK general election?

Tags: united-kingdom, election, conservative-party

It is quite possible that Mr Johnson loses his seat in the upcoming general election, while the Conservative party gains a majority.

Does the Conservative party have official procedures for what would happen?

Comment: Possible in theory but hardly probable. Did you look who his counter-candidates are for that seat? How many 20-something years-old Muslim MPs are in the Parliament?

Comment: Although a strange situation, he could still continue as leader of the party. The SNP, Green, DUP and Plaid have party leaders that do not have seats in the commons, he would however not be able to be PM as he would not be a member of either the Lords or Commons. There is no constitutional rule that links PM and party leader just that usually the party leader of the largest party is the person who commands the confidence of the house.

Answer (score 6):

He would have two options if this was the case. One is he could step down and the conservative party could appoint a replacement. Second is he could technically continue in the post if he was appointed a lord.

https://metro.co.uk/2019/11/07/will-boris-still-prime-minister-loses-seat-11057766/

> If Mr Johnson does lose his seat, he could technically continue as Prime Minister so long as the Conservative Party win a majority. But he would have to appoint himself a Lord.

However

> In this unlikely event, he would face an enormous amount of pressure to resign and would probably be replaced by another Tory MP in a leadership election.

Comment: By-election in safe seat seems more likely. No idea what would happen during the interim though.

Comment: @Jontia That interim is the problem as there will be a need for a PM and he won't be able to fill the spot without some work.

Comment: @Jontia: it's happened before, sort of: Alec Douglas-Home was a Lord when he became PM. While still being PM, he disclaimed his peerage, was neither a Lord nor an MP for a few days, then won a by-election in a safe seat.